# Angular 5 ngx-bootstrap modal or modal in general, handle all types of close including esc

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

UPDATE AGAIN :

[image]

The context :

I have a reusable modal component which according to the content it receives upon creation (timeline component) :

```
createNewTimelineItemModal(): Promise<Object> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const initialState = {
        title: 'Add',
        multipleChoice: 'Bid <i class="fa fa-telegram"></i>',
        choices: [
          'Bid <i class="fa fa-telegram"></i>',
          'D.C. <i class="fa fa-bandcamp"></i>',
          'Kick-off <i class="fa fa-grav"></i>'],
        accceptBtnName: 'Add',
        closeBtnName: 'Cancel',
      };
      this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(Modal, {initialState});
      this.bsModalRef.content.onClose.subscribe(result => { 
        resolve(this.createItemResult = result);
      })
    });
  }

  errorTimelineItemModal(): Promise<Object> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const initialState = {
        title: 'Sorry',
        list: ['Sorry, for the moment, creating or moving items to weekends is disabled.']
      };
      this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(Modal, {initialState});
      this.bsModalRef.content.onClose.subscribe(result => { 
        resolve(this.createItemResult = result);
      })
    });
  }
```

...can do things ranging from create an item with custom name to simply notify the user of an error.

these modals are called thusly (timeline component) :

```
onUpdate: (item, callback) => {
      if(this.timeline.getCurrentTime() < item.start){
        this.updateTimelineItemModal(item.content).then((res) => {
        if( res['valid']){
          item.content = res['update'];
          callback(item);
        } else callback(null);
        });
      }
    },
```

or in a simpler case (timeline component) :

```
 this.errorTimelineItemModal().then((res) => {this.errorModalOpen = false});
```

as you can see; acting upon these modals' end-of-life is part of my calling component's prerogative.

I make sure to provide a promise at the end of the modal's lifecycle (modal html) :

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">{{title}}</h4>
  <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="onCancel()">
        .....[some Modal content].....
  <div *ngIf="closeBtnName || accceptBtnName" class="modal-footer">
    <button *ngIf="closeBtnName" type="button" class="btn btn-airbus" (click)="onCancel()">{{closeBtnName}}</button>
  </div> 
</div>
```

(modal component) :

```
  onCancel() { // notice v this !!!
    this.onClose.next(this.answer);
    this._bsModalRef.hide();
  }
```

There are five different ways of closing the modal some of which properly emit promise, **some of which do not** :

1. clicking on the validate button (if present) (will send back that valid is true as part of the returned object along with whichever necessary values)
2. clicking on the cancel button (if present) (will send back the same object but valid will be false and other values will be empty)
3. hitting the <kbd>esc</kbd> key (this used to be unhandled; as in : the default behavior would be to close the modal which is ok but no promise would be emitted, thanks to this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49628544/4770754 I now correctly emit promise)
4. **clicking inside the modal (this closes the modal and is not caught by my modal so far, therefore I cannot tell it to call my `onCancel()`**
5. **clicking outside the modal (same)**

I need to find a way to catch modal close in it's entirety and prevent it and trigger my personal cancel method instead.

I'll settle for catching both specific types of clicks.

PS: there are no other `(click)=""` DOM attributes in the modal html then the ones I showed you so it is something hidden in `ngx-bootstrap`'s js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here you can see the implementation](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/modal/modal.directive.ts) of the escape keypress:

```
  @HostListener('window:keydown.esc', ['$event'])
  onEsc(event: any): void {
    if (event.keyCode === 27) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    if (this.config.keyboard) {
      this.dismissReason = DISMISS_REASONS.ESC;
      this.hide();
    }
  }
```

You can define your own listener like this, use the information that it only calls`this.hide()`, or just run your logic async to this behaviour.

**Update:** to handle the outside click, also from the implementation:

```
 @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onClick(event: any): void {
    if (
      this.config.ignoreBackdropClick ||
      this.config.backdrop === 'static' ||
      event.target !== this._element.nativeElement
    ) {
      return;
    }
    this.dismissReason = DISMISS_REASONS.BACKRDOP;
    this.hide(event);
  }
```

The interesting part is the `event.target !== this._element.nativeElement`. This part decides if the click is inside our outside.

Comment: that worked for me! thanks! :) .... I just used the first if and called my `this.onCancel();` after the  `preventDefault`.

Comment: woops. this does not account for clicking in the grey backdrop to close.

Comment: I just want to catch any type of close and make those call `onClose()`

Comment: I am not sure I understand you :S This code that I provided is the official implementation. As far as I know, there is **no way of removing @HostListeners**, so you either live with it and change your logic around the issue, or, use a custom implementation instead of the official.

Comment: No I meant I need to catch the click outside event, thanks to you esc works now but that's only the third way of closing a modal, there's a fourth : click outside.

Comment: thanks. that doesn't work for me though. are you sure in ngx-bootstrap that the backdrop isn't part of the modal element?

Comment: if it helps, I **do** manage to catch whether the click is **within** the modal with `event.target !== this._element.nativeElement`. This click anywhere within the modal causes the modal to close, which, you know, why not. I'm fine with that, apart for the fact that it's a disgraceful close. My app isn't aware that it has finished.

Comment: can you provide your code and explain what is the scenario you hope to achive with it?

Comment: fair comment, I updated the OP again. thank you so much for your help thus far!

Comment: any ideas? I tried to make it as clear as possible. As it stands  I think I just need to catch the mouse click exit but what you provided me does not quite suffice.

Comment: I think your problem might be, that if you just copy that code, the `event.target !== this._element.nativeElement` will always be false, as the this._element is not the modal if you are outside the modal's class (which, the code is copied from.) . Try to find that component from the DOM with the [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) annotation, by assinging an id to it or selecting it manually.